# Spock - approximate comparisions

Tags: grails, junit, spock

I’ve been looking for the Spock equivalent of the following convenience method in JUnit whereby you can do “approximate” comparisons. Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

```
/**
 * Asserts that two doubles or floats are equal to within a positive delta.
 */
assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)
```

Comment: You may want to use Hamcrest matchers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is build in function for that, described in [official docs](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_code_hamcrestsupport_expect_code):

```
when:
def x = computeValue()

then:
expect x, closeTo(42, 0.01)
```

Check the [specs](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-specs/src/test/groovy/spock/util/matcher/IsCloseToSpec.groovy).

Comment: This answers the question more specifically. Thanks @Michal_Szulc

Comment: See also Spock release notes mentioning Hamcrest support [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_hamcrest_matcher_syntax) and [there](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_code_hamcrestsupport_expect_code).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a Spock equivalent but it's easy to write your own

```
class Foo extends Specification {

  private boolean compareApproximately(Number expected, Number actual, Number delta) {
    Math.abs(expected - actual) <= delta
  }

  def "approximate test"() {
    expect:
    compareApproximately(4, 4.5, 1)
    !compareApproximately(4, 4.5, 0.1)
  }
}
```

In practice, you'd probably want to make `compareApproximately` reusable across specs by defining it in a trait, subclass of `Specification`, or a static method in a utility class.